Unable to import file that's in the same folder as the file I'm importing in
I'm coding a Discord bot and wanted to have a utilities file that I can import functions from so my other files don't get too cluttered. All of the bot's files are in a folder called Science_Bot. Science_Bot contains a folder called utils, which in turn contains the utilities file, sci_utils.py. I'm trying to import sci_utils.py to two other files that are also in the Science_Bot folder but aren't in the utils folder. I first tried:
import sci_utils
and was then told the module "sci_utils" didn't exist. I then tried
from utils import sci_utils
and
import utils.sci_utils
and got the same error message.
Things I've tried include:

Appending utils and Science_Bot to sys.path. Printing sys.path has told me that they are currently in there, so there was no problem actually executing this.
Creating a new environment path. I created a new environment path called PYTHONPATH and set it as my utils file. When I check my environment paths, PYTHONPATH is in there and my desired folder is set as the path.
Checking properties:security settings for folders involved, such as Science_Bot, utils, and basically every higher-level folder than contains Science_Bot. My laptop has complete permissions for all of these folders.


Create __init__.py file, even if empty it will do the trick.
It marks the dir you put it in as a package so you can import easily.
For export out of the dir you might need to fill the init file but its not your case.

I'm so happy I could cry. This worked. Thank you so much.

Sure, happy to help :) just mark the answer as the answer so the case is closed.
